# Show that there is a subsequence of $F_n$ converging to zero almost everywhere.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

If F is a positive $L^1$  function on R.
Define $F_n = F(x+n)$. Show that there is a subsequence of $F_n$ converging to zero almost everywhere.

If I can show that $F_n$ converges to 0 in measure or if I could show $F_n$ converges in L1 norm then in both cases I think I am done. but I do not know how to get started.

Comment: $F_n$ does **not** converge to zero in $L^1$, since $\Vert F_n \Vert_{L^1} = \Vert F \Vert_{L^1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: @PhoemueX .I believe he should have said "$F_n(x)$ converges to $0$ for almost all $x$." If  $F(x)=1/(1+x^2)$  then $F_n (x)$ converges to $0$   (pointwise)  for all $x$. Of course $F_n$ does not converge to $0$ in norm.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to slightly modify a standard proof that convergence in measure implies pointwise almost everywhere convergence of a subsequence. Let  $$A_n(k)=\{x\in(-k,\infty)\colon |F_n(x)|>2^{-k}\}.$$ For each $k\in\mathbb N$, there exists $N_k\in\mathbb N$ such that $\mu(A_n(k))<2^{-k}$ for all $n\geq N_k$. We may assume that $N_1\leq N_2\leq \cdots$. Because $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(A_{N_k}(k))<\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}<\infty,$$ it follows from the Borel-Cantelli lemma that $$\mu\left(\limsup_{k\to\infty}A_{N_k}(k)\right)=0.$$ If $x\in\mathbb R$ is such that $F_{N_k}(x)$ does not converge to $0$ as $k\to\infty$, then $x$ must belong to infinitely many of the sets $A_{N_k}(k)$. In other words, the set of points at which $F_{N_k}$ does not converge to $0$ is contained in the null set $\displaystyle \limsup_{k\to\infty} A_{N_k}(k)$. Thus, $F_{N_k}$ converges to $0$ pointwise almost everywhere.